# x88 Max+ Android Hide On Screen Keyboard

Tags: external-keyboard, android-tv, 9.0-pie

This little box is so close to replacing my PC but it has a number of frustrating issues that I would like to fix (it's running Android 9.0).

The on screen keyboard won't go away. I have show virtual keyboard turned off in physical keyboard settings but it still appears.

The enter key enters the currently selected key on the physical keyboard instead of enter. I know how to fix this by rooting the device but I don't know how to root the device (and I'd rather not root the device if I can avoid it).

The cursor keys control the selected key on the on screen keyboard instead of the cursor position on the screen.

Selecting a suggested search term in Google Chrome with the mouse while typing in the URL/Search bar doesn't work (does nothing).

If I can fix the on screen keyboard issues this box will be good enough to replace my PC! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use External Keyboard Helper Pro app to do this on the T95Q, I assume on the X88 MAX Plus too (I got rid of mine as it cannot do VPN over Ethernet).